# Sidekiq is not successfully reporting errors to rollbar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq, rollbar

I got an application using `rollbar` and `sidekiq` and for some reason all errors occuring in sidekiq (in the logs where rollbar URLs are logged) are not posted. Whenever I try to open one of the items, I get:

```
UUID not found. It may still be processing. Hit refresh?
```

`rollbar` and `sidekiq` are default installations so if any info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Sidekiq provide "jid" not uuid

Comment: Ok and can you tell me how to change it to `uuid`? Google couldn't and I haven't heard of it before.

Comment: @Cojones the errors will only appear if reporting was successful. Sounds like reporting is failing. Do you have your Rollbar access token correctly configured in your environment?

Comment: Yes, errors coming from the app itself are always reported successfully. Only the errors occuring in Sidekiq are not reported at all.